# Why can't my Docker container find the file it's supposed to create?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container (Linux container running on Windows with VLS 2) running a .NET Core 5.0 application, whose `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` were created by someone else. I spun it up with `docker run` and passing a single environment variable and port mapping. It works just fine until it attempts to create a file, which it attempts to do with a statement like this: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText($"/output_json/myfile.json", jsonString);`, and errors out. The error message says

```
Could not find a part of the path '/output_json/myfile.json'.
```

Since a Docker container is essentially a virtualized filesystem, I assume I need to allocate some space to the container, or share a folder on the host machine with it, so that it has an accessible location to save the file. Is that correct?

EDIT: I've just found this in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  <servicename>:
    volumes:
      - ./output:/output_json
```

Doesn't this mean that an `output_json` directory is supposed to be created? Does `docker-compose` not have any bearing on a container created with `docker run`?

Comment: if the file is on the host machine, you will need to use a [volume](https://thenewstack.io/docker-basics-how-to-share-data-between-a-docker-container-and-host/) in order to share data between both environments

Comment: It looks like the `docker-compose` file specifies a volume (see my edit). Will I need to change permissions when creating the container so it can write to it or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/output_json` probably doesn't exist in the docker image. That could be because you're meant to map a directory on your host to that path. Then the container can put it's output there and you can grab it after the container is done.

To try it, you can make an empty directory and map that to the `/output_json` path in your container by running the following 2 commands from a command line

```
mkdir %temp%\container_output
docker run -v %temp%\container_output:/output_json <other options> <image name>
```

Then do `cd %temp%\container_output` and see what output the container has made.

Comment: I just discovered that `docker-compose.yml` appears to have a "volumes" section (see my edit). Do I need to find the location that it's supposed to be mapped to and ensure the folder exists?